# how to modify existing cookie by adding multiple value to it in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, cookies

I want to store some data to clients device in the form of cookie . this data consist of numbers. ones the client goes through a particular page I want that page number to be stored on the client's device in the form of cookie. and when client goes to another page I want to push in that new page's value as well to the existing value of the previous page. I want to store this all in array so that it can be used by my website to show client appropriate page suggestions on his next visit. The code done by me is below. it doesn't work properly. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
$name ="namehere";
if (!isset($_COOKIE['namehere'])) {
    $name ="namehere";
    $myArr = array("1", "4", "6", "8","5","9");
    $count = array_count_values($myArr);
    $myJSON = json_encode($myArr);

    setcookie('namehere', $myJSON, time() + (60*60*24*1), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
    echo "Cookie named $name is not set!";
}
else {
    echo "Cookie named $name is set!<br>";
    $cookieloaded = $_COOKIE['namehere'];
    $myjson = json_decode($cookieloaded);
    $pushin = array_push($myjson,"11");

    $mynewJSON = json_encode($pushin);

    setcookie('namehere', $mynewJSON, time() + (60*60*24*1), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
    echo $_COOKIE['namehere'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I check your code and there was a mistake with a function. Try with the next:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['namehere'])) {
    $name ="namehere";
    $myArr = array("1", "4", "6", "8","5","9");
    $count = array_count_values($myArr);
    $myJSON = json_encode($myArr);

    setcookie('namehere', $myJSON, time() + (60*60*24*1), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
    echo "Cookie named $name is not set!";
}
else {
    echo "Cookie named $name is set!<br>";

    $cookieloaded = $_COOKIE['namehere'];
    $myjson = json_decode($cookieloaded,true);
    $myjson[] = "11";

    $mynewJSON = json_encode($myjson);

    setcookie('namehere', $mynewJSON, time() + (60*60*24*1), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
    echo $_COOKIE['namehere'];
}


json_decode(json, true) => true to convert json to array
array_push($myjson,"11");  => $myjson is a pointer, replace to $myjson[] = 11;
```

I simulated some times and the code adds 11 to the cookie in each test.

Comment: thanks a lot Mr. Maximiliano your advice worked well. Thanks for giving your valuable times, I was struggling  on this problem since past two days now it is resolved by your advice.Thanks.